# Select most recent purchase prior to the latest purchase

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
customer_id  purchase_date  category
1            9/1/2018       Electronics
1            9/2/2018       Art
1            9/3/2018       Books
1            9/5/2018       CPG
2            9/2/2018       Books
2            9/4/2018       Electronics
2            9/20/2018      CPG
```

From here, I am trying to derive the most recent purchase prior to a CPG purchase. To explain further, here are my steps:

Step 1. create a table of purchases not in CPG category:

```
WITH OTHERS AS(
    SELECT customer_id,
           category as others_category,
           purchase_date
    FROM orders o
    WHERE category IN ('Electronics', 'Books', 'Art')
),
```

Step 2. Create a table of purchases in CPG category:

```
CPG AS( 
    SELECT customer_id,
           category as cpg_category,
           purchase_date
    FROM orders o
    WHERE category = 'CPG'
)
```

Step 3.Left join:
This is where I am stuck. I would like to produce a table that has the most recent OTHER purchase prior to a CPG purchase. i.e, the output should look like:

```
others_category  count_distinct_customers
Electronics            1
Books                  1
```

Ideally I would like to not use CTE. 
SQL type is SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Just for clarification, would count_distinct_customers ever have more than 1 if you're looking at the purchase prior to CPG?

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` should easily solve this problem.

Comment: @GreyOrGray Yes! If multiple people purchased a book prior to CPG (which is the case in my full dataset), count_distinct_customer would be > 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it in SQL Server 2017, however, I'm not certain if this'll work in 2005 (unfortunately, like i said, I don't have a 2005 test environment anymore). I *think* `APPLY` was added in SQL Server 2008. Certainly the "VTE" won't work in 2005, as the `VALUES` constructor clause was added in 2008 (if I recall correctly), however, you'll have a table to test against at least:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT V.customer_id,
           CONVERT(date,V.purchase_date,101) AS purchase_date,
           V.category
    FROM (VALUES(1,'9/1/2018 ','Electronics'),
                (1,'9/2/2018 ','Art'),
                (1,'9/3/2018 ','Books'),
                (1,'9/5/2018 ','CPG'),
                (2,'9/2/2018 ','Books'),
                (2,'9/4/2018 ','Electronics'),
                (2,'9/20/2018','CPG')) V(customer_id,purchase_date,category))
SELECT V2.category,
       COUNT(DISTINCT V2.customer_id) AS DistinctCustomers
FROM VTE V1
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                         customer_id,
                         purchase_date,
                         category
                  FROM VTE ca 
                  WHERE ca.customer_id = V1.customer_id
                    AND ca.purchase_date < V1.purchase_date
                  ORDER BY ca.purchase_date DESC) V2

WHERE V1.category = 'CPG'
GROUP BY V2.category;
```

Comment: CROSS APPLY was added in SQL Server 2005, so he should be able to use it. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase, you only want purchases that were immediately followed by a "CPG Purchase" (by the same customer?).

The analytic function `LEAD()` allows you to find what is in the "following" row, without having to join the data back on itself.

```
WITH
  orders_with_lookup AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    LEAD(category) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY purchase_date)   AS customers_next_purchase_category
  FROM
    orders
)
SELECT
  category,
  COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)   AS count_distinct_customers
FROM
  orders_with_lookup
WHERE
  customers_next_purchase_category = 'CPG'
GROUP BY
  category
ORDER BY
  category
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OUTER APPLY (available since SQL Server 2005) to join every CPG order with its previous purchase of OTHERS, and then you can just return that OTHERS order data.

I have added a DISTINCT, so if two CPG orders have the same OTHERS previous order (because no others orders have been entered between them) then it's only returned once.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT others.*
   FROM orders cpg
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT top 1 others.*
                     FROM orders as others
                     WHERE category <> 'CPG' and
                           others.purchase_date < cpg.purchase_date
                           order by others.purchase_date desc) as others
   WHERE category = 'CPG'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
;WITH CTE(customer_id , purchase_date , category)
AS
(
SELECT 1,'9/1/2018' ,'Electronics' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'9/2/2018' ,'Art'         UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'9/3/2018' ,'Books'       UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'9/5/2018' ,'CPG'         UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'9/2/2018' ,'Books'       UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'9/4/2018' ,'Electronics' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'9/20/2018','CPG'     
)
,CTE2 
AS
(
SELECT customer_id,purchase_date,category, 
       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY purchase_date DESC) AS MostRecentPurchase
FROM
(
SELECT customer_id , 
       CAST( purchase_date AS DATE) purchase_date, 
       category
FROM CTE
)dt
)
SELECT Category AS Others_category,
       COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) AS Count_distinct_customers
FROM  CTE2
WHERE  MostRecentPurchase = 2
GROUP BY category
```

Result

```
Others_category     Count_distinct_customers
-----------------------------------------
Books                   1
Electronics             1
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is yet another approach...so many ways to skin this cat.

```
declare @Something table
(
    customer_id int
    , purchase_date date
    , category varchar(20)
)
insert @Something values
(1, '9/1/2018 ', 'Electronics')
, (1, '9/2/2018 ', 'Art')
, (1, '9/3/2018 ', 'Books')
, (1, '9/5/2018 ', 'CPG')
, (2, '9/2/2018 ', 'Books')
, (2, '9/4/2018 ', 'Electronics')
, (2, '9/20/2018', 'CPG')

, (3, '9/2/2018 ', 'Books') --added customer 3 
, (3, '9/4/2018 ', 'Electronics')
, (3, '9/20/2018', 'CPG')

select category
    , DistinctCustomerCount = count(*)
from
(
    select *
        , RowNum = row_number()over(partition by customer_id, case when category = 'CPG' then 1 else 0 end order by purchase_date desc)
    from @Something
) x
where x.category <> 'CPG'
    and x.RowNum = 1
group by x.category
```